# Error: Data truncated for column 'lat' at row 1

Tags: php, mysql, database

i want store my point on map into mysql database by submit form.
my 'lat' data is float(25,20) and i try to save 37.41590458202049 in this field.
but i get this error:'Error: Data truncated for column 'lat' at row 1'

Comment: please be more specific and give more information like the sql that you used to create and update table.and I'm sure you could find your answer by searching it on google or SO.

Comment: i use mysql for create database. i was searched to find answer for solution and i can not fix this error

Comment: as you taged mysql so I know you are using it :) how did you create the table, I think it is length problem.

Comment: i create table in mysql coment. but changethis with phpmyadmin of WAMP server

Answer (score 0):

Length of data is more than the specified length of your column. Just increase the length of your column.

Comment: length of my data is (16,14) and length of column is(25,20)!!